# HTML <a> download link does not working

Tags: html, download

```
<img href='../img/image.jpg' download>Download</a>
```

I think i know the problem , may be using "**../**" cause the download does not work , but i have not idea for this.
I am trying many kind of method to this, and also not working.
Does it have any syntax can replace ../ ?

Someone have any experience for this?

It would help me in my assignment...

Comment: i  was wrong word <img> , it should be <a>..

Comment: is this solution working for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify this with an a tag so it would be like this

```
<a href="path/to/image" download="Your Image Name"><img src="path/to/image" /></a>
```

Comment: /*My Folder*/
main(level 1)
   img(level 2) <- image's folder need to get
   web(level 2)
       current(level 3) <- current website

on the html i am wrote href='/main/img/image.jpg' that also not work to download

Comment: take the slash off of the front of the your href so it would be <a href="main/img/image.jpg" download="Your Image Name"><img src="main/img/image.jpg" /></a>

Comment: I also see that your page is in a subfolder in your above example so using your example above it would be href="../img/image.jpg" use whatever you use for the src of the image.